# Internal storage missing: Nexus 7 16G down to 5.8G TOTAL

Tags: internal-storage, nexus-7, partitions

My Nexus 7 now believes it has only 5G internal storage. It's shown in storage properties.

I noticed it after factory reset, and then a 4.3 update (I remember getting 4.3 OTA update twice, is it possible?)

I installed ClockworkMod recovery (back when it was on 4.2), but never rooted it.

No storage space analyzers show hidden files or such. Rebooting doesn't change anything.

I found /sdcard/0 directory with a content of my previous sdcard before a factory reset, deleting it freed some space, but total is still at 5.8G.

I found [one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=28959386&postcount=8) complaint about a similar situation, but it's drowned in a simpler problems and was never answered.

`df` output:

```
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                   487.4M    32.0K   487.3M   4096
/mnt/secure            487.4M     0.0K   487.4M   4096
/mnt/asec              487.4M     0.0K   487.4M   4096
/mnt/obb               487.4M     0.0K   487.4M   4096
/system                639.8M   515.7M   124.1M   4096
/cache                 436.0M     7.3M   428.7M   4096
/data                    5.9G     2.7G     3.2G   4096
/mnt/shell/emulated      5.9G     2.7G     3.2G   4096
/mnt/asec/com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime-1     2.0M    84.0K     1.9M   4096
/mnt/asec/com.loudcrow.goodnightmoon-1     5.0M     3.4M     1.6M   4096
```

`cat /proc/partitions` output:

```
major minor  #blocks  name
   7        0       2111 loop0
   7        1       5229 loop1
 179        0    7467008 mmcblk0
 179        1      12288 mmcblk0p1
 179        2       8192 mmcblk0p2
 179        3     665600 mmcblk0p3
 179        4     453632 mmcblk0p4
 179        5        512 mmcblk0p5
 179        6      10240 mmcblk0p6
 179        7       5120 mmcblk0p7
 179        8        512 mmcblk0p8
 179        9    6302720 mmcblk0p9
 179       32       2048 mmcblk0boot1
 179       16       2048 mmcblk0boot0
 254        0       2110 dm-0
 254        1       5229 dm-1
```

`mount` output:

```
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/secure tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=700 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/platform/sdhci-tegra.3/by-name/APP /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/sdhci-tegra.3/by-name/CAC /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,nomblk_io_submit,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/sdhci-tegra.3/by-name/UDA /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,errors=panic,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,nomblk_io_submit,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/shell/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/block/dm-0 /mnt/asec/com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime-1 ext4 ro,dirsync,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1 0 0
/dev/block/dm-1 /mnt/asec/com.loudcrow.goodnightmoon-1 ext4 ro,dirsync,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1 0 0
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem on the same device: 6.02GB total after a reset and upgrade (to 4.4.3)

Comment: Nope, I'm stuck with it. I planned to reflash by wire, and maybe take a look at partition table, but never had time for it.

Comment: Can't say I figured it out, but I got it working, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my N7.  The answer for me was to lock the boot loader, then unlock it again.

Hope this helps and saves some time instead of flashing the entire OS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as OP flashing to 4.4.3 on a Nexus 7 16GB (2012).  My total storage as reported by the storage module of the settings app was like 6GB and running `df` from BusyBox/adb was reporting the same.  This is clearly a partition table problem and not hidden files or anything else.  I think that the problem was caused by several failed/aborted flashes that I did.  I was able to fix it by reflashing from adb.

In other words, I downloaded [the latest image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), decompressed it, and ran the `flash_all.sh` script.  (Of course after running `adb reboot-bootloader`).

For the record, I did NOT have to change the commands to `fastboot format X`.

It would be nice to understand this problem better but for the time being, going from ~6GB to >13GB of usable space is quite a relief.

Answer (score -2):

If you download an external file viewer, root explorer, oi file manager .ect. Then go to dcim on the phone or external sd card and there most likely is a file that is unknown when you click it and usually has several hundreds of megabytes take up on it, you can just delete it, also, it shoulf say thumb data

Comment: No. I said there are no hidden files and storage analyzers don't find such. And this won't decrease TOTAL storage volume. Thanks for your answer though.